# How can I simplify this helper function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on a flutter application and noticed a lot of code being repeated in different modules so, I started implementing a generic module using which all other module can created in only a few lines of code.

Anyways, I have a function whose body looks like this. I was wondering if there is any way I can simplify it.

```
class HelperClass<T> {
    ...
    T func1(dynamic element) {
        T object;
        switch (T) {
          case ClassA:
            object = ClassA.func1(element) as T;
            break;
          case ClassB:
            object = ClassB.func1(element) as T;
            break;
          default:
            throw UnimplementedError("func1 for Type $T not handled!");
        }
        return object;
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: if the functions are same i.e. `func1`, then do you really need switch case statement? could you avoid it by having a single T.func1(element)?

Comment: @JoyTerence You cannot call static methods on generics like `T.func1`.

Comment: @julemand101, ah I see thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could redesign `HelperClass` so that callers are required to supply `ClassA.func1`, `ClassB.func1`, etc. as callbacks instead, and then `HelperClass` could invoke the callback with `element` unconditionally:

```dart
class HelperClass<T> {
  HelperClass(this._func1);

  T Function(dynamic) _func1;

  T func1(dynamic element) => _func1(element);
}
```

and then callers would use it with `HelperClass<ClassA>(ClassA.func1)`.

A similar approach would be to make a factory class that does this:

```dart
class ClassAFactory {
   ClassA create(dynamic element) => ClassA.func1(element);
}
```

and then pass an instance of the factory to `HelperClass<T>`.  That might be simpler if you need to do this for multiple functions.